# Angular 8 and Typescript 3.8 issue

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

```
export interface ProductState{
showProductCode: boolean;
currentProduct: Product;
products: Product[];
}     

const InitialValue ={
showProductCode: true,
currentProduct: null,
products: []
} as ProductState;

export function reducer(state: InitialValue, action): ProductState{
switch(action.type){

    case 'TOGGLE_PRODUCT_CODE':
        console.log('exisiting state :' + JSON.stringify(state));
        console.log('payload :' + action.payload);    
        return{
            ...state,
            showProductCode: action.payload
        };
    default:
        return state;
}
}
;
```

Getting error

```
{
"resource": "...",
"owner": "typescript",
"code": "2749",
"severity": 8,
"message": "'InitialValue' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.",
"source": "ts",
"startLineNumber": 40,
"startColumn": 32,
"endLineNumber": 40,
"endColumn": 44
```

}

Comment: `InitialValue` is an object here, not a type. You should declare `state: ProductState` in your reducer function

Comment: @David How to set default value in reducer function state parameter.

Comment: `state: ProductState = InitialValue`

Comment: thanks a lot @David..